# ios swift facebook login fb_mobile_login_native_app_switch_dialog_result error

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the facebook swift sdk.

When I click on the login button I get this warning/error:

```
FBSDKLog: Invalid identifier: 'fb_mobile_login_native_app_switch_dialog_result'. Must be between 1 and 40 characters, and must be contain only alphanumerics, _, - or spaces, starting with alphanumeric or _.
```

My code:

```
@IBAction func fbLoginBtnDidTouch(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email"], from: self) { (result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){

                let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result!

                if (result?.isCancelled)! {
                    return
                }

                if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
                {
                    self.getFBUserData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    func getFBUserData(){
        if((FBSDKAccessToken.current()) != nil){
            FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, email"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                if (error == nil){
                    let fbJson = JSON(result ?? [])
                    if let fbId = fbJson["id"].string, let fbEmail = fbJson["email"].string {

                        self.fetchedFbId = fbId
                        self.fetchedFbEmail = fbEmail

                        var fbLoginParams = [String: Any]()

                        fbLoginParams["facebook_id"] = fbId

                        self.createFbAccount(fbLoginParams)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Into info.plist file under the app target you would need to add:

**FacebookAppID**

```
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>123456789012345</string>
```

**CFBundleURLTypes**

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb123456789012345</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

**LSApplicationQueriesSchemes:**

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

Facebook app ID retrieved from the Facebook developer portal.